# What purpose does ODBCParameters setting serve in DB2 configuration?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

When I export my DB2 configuration (that was set up by an administrator) using db2cfexp, I have some CLI entries that have an `ODBCParameters` setting.

Here's an example:

```
[CLI_ODBC>SMPLE1]
DataSourceName=SMPLE1
DataSourceType=System
DBALIAS=SMPLE1
ODBCParameters=Yes

[CLI_ODBC>SMPLE2]
DataSourceName=SMPLE2
DataSourceType=System
DBALIAS=SMPLE2
ODBCParameters=No
```

What is the purpose of the `ODBCParameters=Yes` and `ODBCParameters=No` setting? I have searched for an explanation but found nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: Won't put this as an answer, but I think it affects how the driver handles .Net [OdbcParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2) data type conversion and such.

Comment: IBM chose not to document this in any meaningful way in the Db2 Knowledge Centre. If you have a paid support contract, why not open a ticket and ask IBM? Otherwise try asking on developerworks forum db2luw answers.